# How to create an empty spreadsheet using Zend GData

Tags: zend-framework, spreadsheet, gdata, zend-gdata

How to create a new, empty spreadsheet using Zends GData Library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/), to create a new, empty spreadsheet: follow the instructions in [Creating a new document or file with metadata only](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_a_new_document_or_file_with_metadata_only). When doing so, use a category term of http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#spreadsheet.

With Zend GData library, it may look like this:

```
// Load Zend library
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Docs');

// Authentication
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('you@there.com', 'sunshine-', Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);

// Get interface to Documents List API
$docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);

// Create new document
$data = new Zend_Gdata_Docs_DocumentListEntry();
$data->setCategory(
      array(new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Category(
              "http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#spreadsheet",
              "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
)));
$data->setTitle(new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Title("My brand new spreadsheet", null));

// Add document to your list
$doc = $docs->insertDocument($data, Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI);

// Display document ID
print($doc->getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this at this moment.

> The Spreadsheets data API does not currently provide a way to
>   programmatically create or delete a spreadsheet.

quote from [official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html#zend.gdata.spreadsheets.creating)

Comment: Yes, true, but if I remember, you can do this with google-drive-api. I saw it in the google DrEdit tutorial somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
     $service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
     $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('USERNAME', 'PASSOWRD', $service);
     $docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);

     // A file I use as a template for this [ based on the extension is the type of document that will be created] 
     // see: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.docs.html
     $fileToUpload = 'Rates-Template.xls'; 
     $newDocumentEntry =  $docs->uploadFile($fileToUpload, 'Spreadsheet Title Here',null, Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI);
```

Comment: I tried your method it just brought an error, upload error, can you upload a file without using a form directly?